Using NetworkPolicy with Maistra Istio
Maistra Istio creates the NetworkPolicy istio-mesh-basic in all istio-enabled namespaces. It looks like this:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    ...
    maistra.io/mesh-generation: 2.6.1-1-5
  labels:
    app: istio
    app.kubernetes.io/component: mesh-config
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: istio-system
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: maistra-istio-operator
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mesh-config
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: istio
    maistra-version: 2.5.4
    maistra.io/member-of: istio-system
    release: istio
  name: istio-mesh-basic
  namespace: ...
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          maistra.io/member-of: istio-system
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress

The label maistra.io/member-of: istio-system is also attached to all istio-enabled namespaces. This completely obliterates the usability of NetworkPolicy for these namespaces. It makes it difficult to combine istio-injected pods and uninjected pods, as it will leave the uninjected pods completely bare. Is there a way to specialize these NetworkPolicys?
